# git add versus git add all

Tags: git, github, terminal, addition

What is the difference between `git add .` and `git add --all .` I read the manual but I still don't get it. Please, in your answer, include how the `.gitignore` file is affected: i.e. does `--all` pretend there is no ignore file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative name for `--all`, which in my opinion is much clearer, is `--no-ignore-removal`. From that alternative name, it may be immediately obvious what it does: if any file is removed in the working tree, it also gets removed in the index.

Having created a fresh repo, and having added a single file, without committing, here's the status:

```
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached ..." to unstage)

        new file:   file
```

Now, here's what happens when the file is deleted, and `git add` is run without `--all`:

```
$ git add .
warning: You ran 'git add' with neither '-A (--all)' or '--ignore-removal',
whose behaviour will change in Git 2.0 with respect to paths you removed.
Paths like 'file' that are
removed from your working tree are ignored with this version of Git.

* 'git add --ignore-removal ', which is the current default,
  ignores paths you removed from your working tree.

* 'git add --all ' will let you also record the removals.

Run 'git status' to check the paths you removed from your working tree.

$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached ..." to unstage)

        new file:   file

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm ..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    file
```

And indeed, `git add -A` will delete it from the index too:

```
$ git add -A .
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

You mention gitignore in your question, but `--all` is unrelated to that. The option to add ignored files is `--force` (`-f`).

Comment: so `git add --all .` will delete on github what ever I have deleted on my local repo? Do I understand that part well?

Comment: @KatedralPillon Very few commands can delete anything on Github or any other remote repo. `git add --all .` will delete files in the index if they've been deleted in your working tree. A subsequent `git commit` will create a local commit that contains the deletion of those files. Only when you then push the commits to Github will you see any change there.